# During window resize, background image scales away from nav bar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm deep into a practice of RWD in a project. I have a `nav` bar and a background image to which I applied a CSS `background-size: contain;` property.

As I resize the browser window to be a smaller width in the view port, The `nav` bar begins to break away from the image and also is scaling the background image. Is there any additional CSS I could apply to have the `nav` bar attach like a magnet to the bottom of the background image?

Will ems help fix that?

Here's a [live example](http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/test.html) - (shrink the browser window width and watch it break apart):

**HTML** & **CSS** code:

```css
#aside_sect_mm {
  margin: 0%;
  background-image: url(../img/mm_main_tab_c.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 704px;
  height: 318px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 704px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 6.5% 0% 0% 0%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 60px;
  color: #FCE011;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 20%;
  background-color: #004E27;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  background-size: 100px 40px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a {
  clear: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F6EF1B;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #F6EF1B;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #004E27;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_grn.svg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>nav bar test</title>
  <link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="aside_sect_mm">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="bio_icon"><a href="#bio">Bio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stat_icon"><a href="#stats">Stats</a>
        </li>
        <li class="img_icon"><a href="#images">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li class="vid_icon"><a href="#videos">Videos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="fut_icon"><a href="#future">Future</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is the `height:318px`.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this kind of approach instead. Having a background image and making it responsive is a bit hard. Make the image embedded into html instead, that would make the responsiveness easier.

```css
#splash-area img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 100%;
}
#aside_sect_mm {
  margin: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 704px;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 704px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 6.5% 0% 0% 0%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 60px;
  color: #FCE011;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 20%;
  background-color: #004E27;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  background-size: 100px 40px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a {
  clear: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F6EF1B;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #F6EF1B;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #004E27;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_grn.svg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>nav bar test</title>
  <link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="splash-area"><img src="http://visionsic.github.io/DSW_II/img/mm_main_tab_c.jpg"/></div>
  <section id="aside_sect_mm">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="bio_icon"><a href="#bio">Bio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stat_icon"><a href="#stats">Stats</a>
        </li>
        <li class="img_icon"><a href="#images">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li class="vid_icon"><a href="#videos">Videos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="fut_icon"><a href="#future">Future</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

```css
#aside_sect_mm {
  margin: 0%;
  background-image: url(../img/mm_main_tab_c.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 704px;
  height: 318px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 704px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 6.5% 0% 0% 0%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 60px;
  color: #FCE011;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 20%;
  background-color: #004E27;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  background-size: 100px 40px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_ylw.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon a,
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon a {
  clear: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F6EF1B;
  overflow: auto;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #F6EF1B;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #004E27;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.bio_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/bio_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.stat_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/stats_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.img_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/img_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.vid_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/vids_ore_grn.svg);
}
#aside_sect_mm nav ul li.fut_icon:hover {
  background-image: url(../svg/fut_ore_grn.svg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>nav bar test</title>
  <link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="aside_sect_mm">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="bio_icon"><a href="#bio">Bio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stat_icon"><a href="#stats">Stats</a>
        </li>
        <li class="img_icon"><a href="#images">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li class="vid_icon"><a href="#videos">Videos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="fut_icon"><a href="#future">Future</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest and fastest way is to set `background-size: cover;` on `#aside_sect_mm`

Comment: The cover property doesn't work in this case. Cover allows the nav bar to remain affixed to the bottom of the image as the browser window is resized, yes that aspect is correct and what i want, but the horizontal z aspect of the image gets cut off by the resize. Not what I'm looking to achieve. I need a percentage scale with the nav bar also scaling with the image and remaining affixed to the bottom of the image.

Comment: you're right it isnt perfect solution, I would do this as img not as background-image then you would save real aspect ratio of image and nav under image would stick

Comment: I'm attempting to avoid adding an image embed into the html , then having to set it to "display none" to cheaply hide it until the browser resizes for responsive reasons. on mobile devices, it creates page load bloat.

Comment: ok so my another idea is to calculate ratio (this background-image) on resize in js and set height and width of container background-image on document ready and then on resize